# I made a rectangle how do I check if the mouse clicked on it?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, hittest, drawrectangle

How do I check if a mouse clicked a rectangle?

```
Graphics gfx;
Rectangle hitbox;
hitbox = new hitbox(50,50,10,10);
//TIMER AT THE BOTTOM
gfx.Draw(System.Drawing.Pens.Black,hitbox);
```

Comment: What does your `gfx` refer to?

Comment: If your "gfx" is a "e.Graphics..." from a form, then just use event MouseDown, there are e.X and e.Y.

Comment: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Answer (score 5):

Just a sample quick and dirty, if your "gfx" is a "e.Graphics..." from a Form:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private readonly Rectangle hitbox = new Rectangle(50, 50, 10, 10);
    private readonly Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, hitbox);
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      if ((e.X > hitbox.X) && (e.X < hitbox.X + hitbox.Width) &&
          (e.Y > hitbox.Y) && (e.Y < hitbox.Y + hitbox.Height))
      {
        Text = "HIT";
      }
      else
      {
        Text = "NO";
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has several handy but often overlooked functions. In this case using the [`Rectangle.Contains(Point)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function is the best solution:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (hitbox.Contains(e.Location)) ..  // clicked inside
}
```

To determine if you clicked on the **outline** you will want to decide on a **width**, since the user can't easily hit a single pixel.

For this you can use either [`GraphicsPath.IsOutlineVisible(Point)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddRectanle(hitbox);
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2f))
      if (gp.IsOutlineVisible(e.location), pen)  ..  // clicked on outline 

}
```

..or stick to rectangles..:

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle inner = hitbox;
    Rectangle outer = hitbox;
    inner.Inflate(-1, -1);  // a two pixel
    outer.Inflate(1, 1);    // ..outline

    if (outer.Contains(e.Location) && !innerContains(e.Location)) .. // clicked on outline
}
```